# @ObservedObject model lifecycle?

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

I'm testing @ObservedObject to test how SwiftUI handles the lifecycle of the model.

As I understand things now, from WWDC videos and documentation, is that the View that creates the model object (a class adopting `ObservableObject`) should use `@StateObject`.

From WWDC videos they clearly state that `@ObservedObject` **does not** own the observed instance lifecycle.

So I created this simple setup:

```
struct TestParentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model:TestModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("TEST TEXT. \(model.name)")
            TestChildView(model: model)
        }
    }
    
}

struct TestParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestParentView(model: TestModel())
    }
}



struct TestChildView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var model:TestModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            print("change name")
            model.changeName()
        }, label: {
            Text("Change Name")
        })

    }
    
}

struct TestChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestChildView(model: TestModel())
    }
}
```

The model I used here is this:

```
class TestModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name:String = ""
    let id = UUID()
    
    
    func changeName() {
        name = "\(UUID())"
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("TestModel DEINIT. \(id)")
    }
    
}
```

When I run this app, I was expecting the TestModel instance created in `TestParentView` to be de-initialized at least at some point since `@ObservedObject` does not own the lifecycle of the `model`.

When I tap on the button to trigger a name change all works, but the TestModel DEINIT never gets called.

From all of this, it looks like `TestParentView` has a **strong** reference to the TestModel and it never lets it go.

So, what do they mean then when they say that `@ObservedObject` does not manage the lifecycle of `model` in this case?

Why is the TestModel DEINIT never called if `@ObservedObject` does not manage the model's lifecycle?

I'm obviously missing something here.

Comment: Just regular ARC, object lives as long as there is at least on strong reference to it. You have one, so it lives.

Comment: Ok, I get that. What do they mean then when they say ObservedObject does not own the lifecycle of the model then and they make a point that we should use StateObject if we want the view to own the lifecycle of the observed instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this View:

```
struct Foo: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TestModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(model.name)
    }
}
```

Every time this view is created, it instantiates a new instance of `TestModel`.

SwiftUI views are really more like view descriptions which are created and destroyed a lot during your app lifecycle. Therefore it's important that the structs are lightweight. The Foo view isn't very lightweight because every rendering pass it instantiates a new model.

If you instead used `@StateObject`, the framework will only instantiate a `TestModel` the first time. After that it will reuse that same instance. This makes it way more performant.

Rule of thumb:

- If the view creates its own model (such as the Foo view), use `@StateObject`.
- If the model is passed in from the outside, use `@ObservedObject`.

---

**To answer your question: "Why is the TestModel DEINIT never called".**

You state that: "When I run this app, I was expecting the TestModel instance created in TestParentView to be de-initialized at least at some point".

The subtle detail is that the TestModel is **not** created in the `TestParentView`, it's merely passed in.

It is created in the `TestParentView_Previews`. And since the body of the `TestParentView_Previews` is only executed once, the TestModel will also only be initialised once, and thus never deallocated.

Comment: So this is spot on what I came to a conclusion too after posting this question. So, why isn't DEINIT called on the test model in my case? Is it because SwiftUI has no reason to recreate my views in my example?

Comment: I've added a section to my answer.

Comment: So what you said makes sense when using the preview in Xcode, but what about when actually running the app in the simulator? That doesn't use TestParentView_Previews. So, I guess in this specific example SwiftUI does not need to destroy and recreate the view and that's why the DEINIT is not called?

Comment: It would depend I think. The exact logic which dictates when views are initialised again is not exactly described by Apple as far as I know. That's an implementation detail of SwiftUI. But I assume that as long as the root view (the parent of `TestParentView`) does not observe the model directly, it does not get recreated.