# @ObservedObject reinit impact on view rendering

Tags: swiftui

From reading one user's answer to [@ObservedObject model lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246045/observedobject-model-lifecycle), where the user says

> Every time this view is created, it instantiates a new instance of TestModel. SwiftUI views are really more like view descriptions which are created and destroyed a lot during your app lifecycle

But I also learned from this article https://blog.scottlogic.com/2020/01/28/Exploring-SwiftUI-3-View-Updates.html that SwiftUI checks if the newly computed view is different from the previous state before rendering it.

So, let's say that the ObservedObject gets recreated, how does that affect the view update? Does SwiftUI compare the previously created view with the new one to see if they are different before updating it, or does a ObservedObject recreation always leads to a new view update.

Hope I am making this question clear.

Comment: Watch Demystify SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

Always leads to a new view update. The reason is the View appears changed because the property for the object will almost certainly have a different pointer compared to last time.

It's like having a memory leak and should be avoided. I'm sure a future version will throw a compilation error if a mistake like `@ObservedObject var obj = SomeObject()` is present. Because the object is instantly dealloced so any async thing it is doing just stops or crashes.